# lxml create CDATA element

Tags: python, lxml, cdata

I am trying to create CDATA element as per https://lxml.de/apidoc/lxml.etree.html#lxml.etree.CDATA

The simplified version of my code looks like this:

```
description = ET.SubElement(item, "description")
description.text = CDATA('test')
```

But when I later try to convert it to string:

```
xml_str = ET.tostring(self.__root, xml_declaration=True).decode()
```

I get an exception

```
cannot serialize <lxml.etree.CDATA object at 0x122c30ef0> (type CDATA)
```

Could you advise me what am I missing?

Here is a simple example:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from lxml.etree import CDATA


root = ET.Element('rss')
root.set("version", "2.0")
description = ET.SubElement(root, "description")
description.text = CDATA('test')
xml_str = ET.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True).decode()
print(xml_str)
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have added a simple example, Python 3.8.10, lxml 4.8.0.

Comment: Use `lxml.etree` _or_ `xml.etree`; don't mix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lxml.etree` and `xml.etree` are two different libraries; you should pick one and stick with it, rather than using both and trying to pass objects created by one to the other.

A working example, using lxml only:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
from lxml.etree import CDATA

root = ET.Element('rss')
root.set("version", "2.0")
description = ET.SubElement(root, "description")
description.text = CDATA('test')
xml_str = ET.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True).decode()
print(xml_str)
```

You can run this yourself at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/JovialMediumLeadership